# In MVC how to identify that the result/data coming from the request is Cached data or Fresh data?

Tags: c#, caching, model-view-controller, outputcache

I have a question related to caching of the content.

In the MVC when we use the statement like [OutputCache(Duration = 120)] it will return the data from the cache till 120sec/ New call to Database will not be established.

Is there any way to identify that the result/data returned is cached data or the fresh data?

For Example: If I am doing two calls to the DataBase within 120 sec, Then in the browser network tab how to identify that which request gave me cached data and which request gave me fresh data?

Comment: bit confused.  the data when it is fetched will be cached.  are you asking: 'how do i tell how `old` the cache is?'

Comment: @JohnB I have furniture the question, Please have a look.